# Библиотека воспроизведения аудио Python + работа в console

Tags: python-3.x, аудио

Требуется библиотека для воспроизведения различных форматов аудио с возможностью проигрывания с заданной позиции (перемотка), а так же приостановлением и управлением громкостью. Чтобы работала без X, поэтому pyglet и pygame не подходят. Как в vlc для пайтон, но без vlc плеера. Если такой библиотеки нет, то как реализовать нужный функционал?

Comment: DirectX SDK и Cython с нуля

Comment: А чуть не забыл ещё есть библиотека pybass

Comment: @Александр, всё думал писать или нет и в итоге ошибся - меня не волнует работа в Windows, поэтому DX - не вариант. ОС на линуксе, в данный момент Arch Linux.

Comment: @Александр, а вот pybass я попробую.